# How to get a result from DialogFragment in the calling Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, datetimepicker, android-dialogfragment

I have the following DialogFragment to pick date:

```
public class Fragment_Picker_Time extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

int hour;
int minute;
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    // Do something with the time chosen by the user
}
}
```

And this is how I call it from another Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.btn_call_time:
        DialogFragment newFragment = new Fragment_Picker_Time();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
        break;
    }
}
```

However I don't know how to get the values from the DialogFragment and pass them to my Fragment. I tried the following:

In the DialogFragment I set the onTimeSet function:

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getParentFragment().getActivity(), Fragment_Schedules.class);
    intent.putExtra("HOUR", hour);
    intent.putExtra("MINUTE", minute);
    getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
}
```

Added the following line to calling this fragment:

```
case R.id.btn_call_time:
        DialogFragment newFragment = new Fragment_Picker_Time();
        newFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 55);
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
        break;
    }
```

And set an `OnActivityResult` function:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    getActivity();
    //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        switch(requestCode)
        {
        case 55:
            int hour   = data.getExtras().getInt("HOUR");
            int minute = data.getExtras().getInt("MINUTE");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "The selected time is: "+hour+":"+minute, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        }
    } else {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

But when I tried to run it my app crashed. This is what I got in logcat:

```
09-29 10:06:43.666: E/AndroidRuntime(14088): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-29 10:06:43.666: E/AndroidRuntime(14088): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-29 10:06:43.666: E/AndroidRuntime(14088):    at com.myname.myproject.fragments.
    Fragment_Picker_Time.onTimeSet(Fragment_Picker_Time.java:32)
09-29 10:06:43.666: E/AndroidRuntime(14088):    at android.app.TimePickerDialog
    .onClick(TimePickerDialog.java:119)
09-29 10:06:43.666: E/AndroidRuntime(14088):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler
    .handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
09-29 10:06:43.666: E/AndroidRuntime(14088):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-29 10:06:43.666: E/AndroidRuntime(14088):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-29 10:06:43.666: E/AndroidRuntime(14088):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-29 10:06:43.666: E/AndroidRuntime(14088):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 10:06:43.666: E/AndroidRuntime(14088):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-29 10:06:43.666: E/AndroidRuntime(14088):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-29 10:06:43.666: E/AndroidRuntime(14088):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-29 10:06:43.666: E/AndroidRuntime(14088):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I pass the selected values from DialogFragment to Fragment?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create an Inteface and your Fragment should implement it.

```
public interface OnTimeDialogListener {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute);       
}
```

Here is the code

```
public class Fragment_Picker_Time extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {


 public interface OnTimeDialogListener {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute);       
 }

 int hour;
 int minute;

 OnTimeDialogListener mListener;    

 @Override
 public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);    
    try {    
        mListener = (OnTimeDialogListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {    
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnTimeDialogListener");
    }
 }

 @Override
 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
  final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
  minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

  // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
  return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
        DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
 }

 public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
      mListener.onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute);
 }
 }
```

Comment: I tried to implement it in my Fragment, but the app crashed, saying I must implement it in my main FragmentActivity. I did managed to implement it in there, but now I need to pass the variables to my Fragment again. Is there a way to pass the values directly to my Fragment?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the line with mListener:

```
mListener=(...Listener)activity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(int RESOURCE);
```

where the last thing in brakets is the id of your fragment in main activity..., for example, R.id.planList. And the first thing in brackets is the name of your Listener, for example, NewPlanNameListener

Than it will indeed direct your click to the fragment, and not to the activity